# how do i convert Dictionary string string to array of key value pair of string and string using linq and c#

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, biztalk

I have a schema generated from BizTalk. it doesn't understand the dictionary collection so it simply converts that to array of key value pair of string and string. Now when i am redirecting the request in a service i get

```
 Dictionary<string, string> valuePairs
```

When i looked in to the reference.cs file i can see like this:

```
public bool ProcessMessage(string code, string template, Service.Proxy.ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] valuePairs)
```

How can i convert this dictionary to array of key value of string string using linq? I know it's easy to do this using linq but any help will really be appreciated.

I have so far tried this but doesn't work:

```
ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] array =
                  valuePairs.Select(pair => string.Format("{0},{1}", pair.Key, pair.Value))
                 .ToArray(KeyValuePair<string,string>);
```

Comment: What is `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring` supposed to be?!

Comment: array of key value pair of string and string the name is so wired it happens during the proxy generation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below , you may need to change the set properties of new object accordingly

```
ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] array =
                  valuePairs.Select(pair =>  
                     new ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring(){
                         Key= pair.Key, Value= pair.Value}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this, which converts your dictionary to the desired array:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvps = valuePairs.ToArray();
```